# Discord.py is throwing a error up for author.send()

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Heres the Error

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Darth\source\repos\PythonApplication2\PythonApplication2\src\main.py", line 20, in on_message
    await message.author.send('y')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 856, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, content, tts=tts, embed=embed, nonce=nonce)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 221, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50007): Cannot send messages to this user
```

It throws this up anytime I try to do

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    if (message.content == 'test'):
        await message.author.send('test')

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

If anyone knows a solution i would be very glad to be able to fix this.

Comment: Check the settings of the mutual servers the bot shares with the users, and the bots permissions on those servers.

Comment: You just helped me realize what it is thx

Answer (score 0):

I just realized i forgot to set the server permissions to allow members to dm each other, Im dumb